# Why url to assets not containing assets word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-sprockets

I did 'rake assets:precompile' in production server and the assets are generated in public/assets folders but rails searches assets with url like domain.com/javascript/application.js, why not like domain.com/assets/application.js, since asssets are present in assets folder. As I deployed app in production environment non of assets are being found with 404 error. Also, why .sprocket-manifest file not created in assets folder.

production.rb has config like:-

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false

  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_files = true # ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = false

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

I have been using rails 4.2.8. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In rails 4 you need to make the changes below:

config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']

This works with me. use following command to pre-compile assets

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Best of luck!